# Exporting Results Of A Querydef To The Active Excel Worksheet

Tags: ms-access, automation, vba

Help! I have a database that I'm using to open an Excel template, export the results of a QueryDef to the acitve worksheet, then save that file with a new file name. Sounds easy enough. The problem that I'm running into is getting the results to export into an active worksheet by using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet. It does everything that I need it to, except for actually transfering the data... Which means, it's pretty much useless. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm about to pull my hair out. Thank you in advance.

Creating the QDF

```
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("" & strCrt, "SELECT [Zones Asset Information].*  FROM " & _
"[Zones Asset Information] WHERE [Zones Asset Informaiton].[Invoice Number] " = '" & strCrt    & "';")
```

Opening the Template

```
  Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets(3)
    xlWS.Activate
```

Trying to Export

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "" & strCrt, , True, "orig data"    'Don't know how to   specify Active Worksheet instead of a filename?!?
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "" & strCrt
```

Saving the File

```
 sSaveAsFileName = FLDR_PATH & "Accounting_Breakdown_Zones_Invoice_xxxxxx.xlsx"
    Debug.Print "sSaveAsFileName: " & sSaveAsFileName
    xlWB.SaveAs sSaveAsFileName
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of exporting data from Access to Excel:

1. Opening an MsExcel object and using its methods to manipulate the Excel
2. Exporting data using the `TransferSpreadsheet` method

You are doing a mix of both, which is why you are not getting the result.

`TransferSpreadsheet` will export the given query to the specified file, but you cannot specify the worksheet.

If specifying worksheet is important, you will have to do it with an Excel object, and send the information cell by cell, a lot more work, if it justifies the cause.

Answer (score 0):

E Mett, Thank you for the direction.  Had to rework the process which doesn't 100% agree with the post title now, but thought I would share in case anyone else needed something similar.  Thanks again!!

```
Private Sub ExportTable_MultipleWB()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset, strFilter As String, strFilter2 As String, _
    sSaveAsFileName As String

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook, xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim bolIsExcelRunning As Boolean

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [mytable].[PO Number], [mytable].[Invoice Number] " & _
                                  "FROM [mytable] ORDER BY [mytable].[PO Number], [mytable].[Invoice Number];", dbOpenSnapshot)

rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF

strFilter = rs.Fields(1).Value
strFilter2 = rs.Fields(0).Value

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [mytable].*  FROM [mytable] WHERE [mytable].[Invoice Number] = '" & strFilter & "';")

On Error Resume Next

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Else
    bolIsExcelRunning = True
End If

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)
Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets(3)

xlWS.Activate

With xlWS

For iCols = 0 To rs2.Fields.Count - 1
    xlWS.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs2.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
    xlWS.Range(xlWS.Cells(1, 1), _
    xlWS.Cells(1, rs2.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
    xlWS.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
End With

sSaveAsFileName = FLDR_PATH & "myfilename_" & strFilter & "_PO-" & strFilter2 & ".xlsx"
    Debug.Print "sSaveAsFileName: " & sSaveAsFileName

xlWB.SaveAs sSaveAsFileName
Set xlWS = Nothing

xlWB.Close False
Set xlWB = Nothing

rs.MoveNext

Loop

rs.Close
rs2.Close

If Not bolIsExcelRunning Then
xlApp.Quit
End If

Set xlApp = Nothing

Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub